# Java/Android/Firebase and being able to stop/restart a TimerTask in an onDataChange method

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timer

I'm trying to start, end, and reset+restart a timer using two different `if` statements in the `onDataChange` method. The thing I can't get to work is getting the timer to restart if the first `if` statement is triggered again after the second one stops the timer. After the class declaration at the top, I have

```
    Timer firstTestTimer = new Timer();
    TimerTask increaseByTwo = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            incrementalCount = incrementalCount + 2;
            System.out.println(incrementalCount);
        }
    };
```

and in the `onCreate` method I have a Firebase reference with a `ValueEventListener` with the following code:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String Motion1 = dataSnapshot.child("Enter").getValue().toString();
                if(Motion1.equals("YES")){
                    incrementalCount = 0;
                    firstTestTimer.schedule(increaseByTwo, 2000,2000);
                }
                if(Motion1.equals("STOP")){
                    firstTestTimer.cancel();
                    firstTestTimer.purge();
                    System.out.println("Total seconds elapsed since sensor showed YES: "+incrementalCount);
                    if(incrementalCount > 11){
                        System.out.println("The difference is greater than 11 seconds");
                    }
                }
            }
```

As of right now, when the Firebase value initially changes to "YES", the timer starts and every two seconds it increases `incrementalCount` by 2. When the Firebase value changes to "STOP", the timer shows the correct amount of seconds that have passed. Here's the problem: When the Firebase value changes to "YES" again, the app crashes and gives me some variation of `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task already scheduled or cancelled`
Is it possible to reset and restart the timer with a fresh count whenever the Firebase value changes to "YES"? Thank you!

Comment: No, it is not possible. The JavaDoc for [`TimerTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimerTask.html) states: "A timer task is not reusable. Once a task has been scheduled for execution on a Timer or cancelled, subsequent attempts to schedule it for execution will throw IllegalStateException." You have to create a new `TimerTask` every time you want to schedule it.

Comment: You have to create the `TimerTask` again as you already canceled it at the `STOP` if statement. You can't reuse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ThomasKläger pointed out, you can't use a `TimerTask` again. The docs point out that:

> A timer task is not reusable. Once a task has been scheduled for execution on a Timer or canceled, subsequent attempts to schedule it for execution will throw IllegalStateException.

It is like a plastic cup or spoon, built to be used only once. So every time you have to increment your timer, here's what you can do:

Leave the timer as it is and define the timer task object again:

```
if (Motion1.equals("YES")){
    incrementalCount = 0;

    //Define it again, I think it is a waste of time to check whether the task exists or not.
    increaseByTwo = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            incrementalCount = incrementalCount + 2;
            System.out.println(incrementalCount);
        }
    };

    firstTestTimer.schedule(increaseByTwo, 2000,2000);
}
```

The rest of the code is the same. This should work.

The documentation for `TimerTask` is here: [TimerTask JDK 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimerTask.html)